# How to show gated sr latch isn't edge triggered?

Tags: electrical-engineering

How do I show this is clearly not edge triggered

[image]

The truth table for this is as follows

| E | R | S | Q | notQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | prevQ | prevnotQ |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | prevQ | prevnotQ |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | prevQ | prevnotQ |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | prevQ | prevnotQ |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | prevQ | prevnotQ |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Edge triggering definition: In edge triggering the circuit becomes active at negative or positive edge of the clock signal. For example if the circuit is positive edge triggered, it will take input at exactly the time in which the clock signal goes from low to high

---

I'm confused how to show this

Comment: Review this link [Edge-triggered Latches: Flip-Flops](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-10/edge-triggered-latches-flip-flops/) In this the output changes on the edge of the Enable signal.  What you have is a [Gated SR Latch](https://www.electrical4u.com/gated-s-r-latches-or-clocked-s-r-flip-flops/) The enable pin has to be active for the output to change. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Enable high.  R & S change output asychronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear in the last three lines of your truth table that the R and S inputs directly influence the output when E is high (no edges). Therefore, not edge-triggered.